# How to intercept electron's request and return a customized response?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron

Suppose the user is able to play an audio on the electron app.

```
<audio id="audio" src="/resource/demo.mp3"></audio>
```

But the file `/resource/demo.mp3` doesn't exist. It's just a url, what I want is that, the request could be intercepted by electron's rendering process, which would extract `demo.mp3` from a zip file and return it to the user, just as follows.

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
const filter = "/resource/**"
electron.interceptRequest(filter, (url) => {
  const audio_name = url.split("/")[2]; // demo.mp3
  const audio_contents = extract_audio_contents_from_zip(audio_name);
  return audio_contents;
});
```

As you can see, it's just like a controller in a web server, is it possible to do so in electron?

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to achieve it.

Write the following code in `main.js`, which is the main process of electron.

```
app.on('ready' () => {
    ...
    let buffer = extractAudioContentsFromZip()
    // the protocol should be prefixed by zip, like zip://test.wav
    protocol.registerBufferProtocol('zip', (request, callback) => {
      callback({
        mimeType: 'audio',
        data: buffer
      });
    });
});
```

Refer to https://electronjs.org/docs/api/protocol for more details.

Comment: What if you used `interceptBufferProtocol`? Do you know what's the difference?